# Powershell - Delete List using powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I need to delete list from a site collection using power shell commands.
Can anyone help me with the code.

[Actual requirement : Delete all list which starts with "xyz"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$startsWith = "ABC"
$site = Get-SPSite http://mycoolsite
$webs = $site.AllWebs

foreach ($web in $webs) {
    $lists = $web.Lists
    for ($index = 0; $index -lt $lists.Count; $index++) {
        if ($lists[$index].Title.StartsWith($startsWith)) {
            $lists[$index].Delete()
        }
    }
    $web.Dispose()
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: can you also provide the generalized code to delete list with list name specified.

Comment: @MonicaJagani - for this generalized code: Do you know web location or do you need to search all webs in site collection to find it? You can easily modify provided code to do second: just use 'if($lists[$index].Title -eq $startsWith)'. This will delete list with name defined in $StartsWith

Comment: It works better if you iterate backwards while deleting; the listed code didn't quite work for me - `for ($index = $lists.Count - 1; $index -ge 0; $index--) {`